# Installing Bundler in PyCharm's venv

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

I'm trying to install [this bundler](https://github.com/snavely/bundler_sfm) onto my pycharm venv, but it doesn't have a pip command. It has a bundler.py file that I can't figure out how to use and the installation process is not very clear. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Have you read `Before you begin` section? https://github.com/snavely/bundler_sfm#before-you-begin

Comment: Yes, but unfortunatelly I can't make it work on my venv @user2235698